# Using rsync to copy database

Tags: cardano-db-sync

I am spinning up another pool. Can I just rsync the database folder, after everything else has been setup?

They're on the same 10GBe switch, so I will try anyway... but just wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can copy the files to speed up the database synchronization on a new freshly installed and configured node. Try to copy all the *db* folder and start the node.

Comment: Success! BP and relay done before I noticed (and I was just using the relay as the source).